# Unit Vectors in Rotation Matrices

Tags: rotations

If I have a rotation matrix $R$, say:

$$R = \begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

when I multiply it by a vector,

$$V' = R.V$$

does the vector necessarily have to be a unit vector for my result to be correct?

Comment: No.  You can rotate non-unit vectors with that same matrix $R$.

Comment: What do you mean by "for my result to be correct"?

Comment: which one is your result? To rotate a vector, it dose not have to be a unit vector, i.e. $Rv$ is the vector $v$, rotate by the angle $\theta$.

Comment: $R$ just rotates each vector counter-clockwise. It doesn't change its length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider some arbitrary vector $\mathbf u$.  It has a magnitude of $\|\mathbf u\|$.  Clearly then, $\hat{\mathbf u} = \dfrac 1{\|\mathbf u\|} \mathbf u$ is the unit vector in the same direction as $\mathbf u$.  Let the rotated unit vector be $R\hat{\mathbf u} = \hat{\mathbf u}'$.  Now let's consider $R\mathbf u = \mathbf u'$.

$$R\mathbf u = R\frac {\|\mathbf u\|}{\|\mathbf u\|}\mathbf u = \|\mathbf u\|R\dfrac 1{\|\mathbf u\|} \mathbf u = \|\mathbf u\|R\hat {\mathbf u} = \|\mathbf u\|\hat{\mathbf u}' = \mathbf u'$$

So this (hopefully) makes it clear that $R\mathbf u$ is the vector which is rotated by $R$ by an angle $\theta$ and has the same length as $\mathbf u$.